# How Enable Right Click in IFRAME with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, iframe, right-click

So I have this IFRAME in my web page, the iframe has a login page (this is part of my domain) but then after the login the iframe redirects the user to an external site (not in my domain) but still is inside the iframe but without the option to right-click (disabled in the HTML code of that external page).

I can enable the right click if I login in that site without an iframe with a simple JavaScript code, but if I access this site through the iframe I'm using, I can't enable the right click there.

This is the code I'm using trying to enable right click:

> javascript:function
>   r(d){d.oncontextmenu=null;d.onselectstart=null;d.ondragstart=null;d.onkeydown=null;d.onmousedown=null;
>   d.body.oncontextmenu=null;d.body.onselectstart=null;d.body.ondragstart=null;d.body.onkeydown=null;
>   d.body.onmousedown=null;};function
>   unify(w){r(w.document);if(w.frames.length>0){for(var
>   i=0;i

So is there any way to enable the right click inside an iframe? even if it is an external domain?

Thanks

**tl;dr: How to enable right click in IFRAME with javascript or any other tool.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot inject Javascript into the external page on a separate domain in the way you describe. Sorry.