# Capture mouse right click event inside a iframe using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, iframe

I need to capture right mouse click event inside a iframe in asp.net using any javascript or jquery codes.

below is the code i have tried so far.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<title>Detect IFrame Clicks</title>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="JScript/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="JScript/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="JScript/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="JScript/jquery.ui.mouse.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">        
    document.onmousedown = onMousebtClick
    var isOverIFrame = false;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        function processMouseOut() {
            isOverIFrame = false;
            top.focus();
        }

        function processMouseOver() {
            isOverIFrame = true;
        }

        function processIFrameClick() {
            if (isOverIFrame) {
                log("CLICK << detected. ");
                onMousebtClick();
            }
        }

        function log(message) {
            var console = document.getElementById("console");
            var text = console.value;
            text = text + message + "\n";
            console.value = text;
        }

        function attachOnloadEvent(func, obj) {
            if (typeof window.addEventListener != 'undefined') {
                window.addEventListener('load', func, false);
            } else if (typeof document.addEventListener != 'undefined') {
                document.addEventListener('load', func, false);
            } else if (typeof window.attachEvent != 'undefined') {
                window.attachEvent('onload', func);
            } else {
                if (typeof window.onload == 'function') {
                    var oldonload = onload;
                    window.onload = function() {
                        oldonload();
                        func();
                    };
                } else {
                    window.onload = func;
                }
            }
        }

        function init() {
            var element = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
            for (var i = 0; i < element.length; i++) {
                element[i].onmouseover = processMouseOver;
                element[i].onmouseout = processMouseOut;
            }
            if (typeof window.attachEvent != 'undefined') {
                top.attachEvent('onblur', processIFrameClick);
            }
            else if (typeof window.addEventListener != 'undefined') {
                top.addEventListener('blur', processIFrameClick, false);
            }
        }

        attachOnloadEvent(init);

    });

    function onMousebtClick() {
        switch (event.button) {
            case 1:
                alert("leftclick");
                break;

            case 2:
                alert("right click");
                break;
        }
    }
    /*document.onmousedown = onMousebtClick*/
</script>

</head>
<body id="mybody">
<iframe src="http://www.microsoft.com" width="800px" height="300px" id="ifrm">
</iframe>
<br />
<br />
<form name="form" id="form" action="">
<textarea name="console" id="console" style="width: 300px; height: 300px;" cols=""
    rows=""></textarea>
<button name="clear" id="clear" type="reset">
    Clear</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

i can able to detect right mouse click in body tag but i can't able to detect the right mouse click event inside the iframe.

Can anyone please help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible if the page inside an `iframe` is on the same domain.

**IFrame page at same domain:** 
http://fiddle.jshell.net/rathoreahsan/MNtw8/8/show/

**See Demo:** 
http://jsfiddle.net/rathoreahsan/gJtkW/

While if you access the page of an other domain inside an `iframe` like you are doing then it is not recommended.

Edited: See some references given below, hope it will be helpful.

1. [the-iframe-cross-domain-policy-problem](http://www.cakemail.com/the-iframe-cross-domain-policy-problem/)
2. [cross-domain-iframe-resizing](http://css-tricks.com/cross-domain-iframe-resizing/)

Comment: Exactly I was trying to explain brother got -1 for it :)

Comment: ++1 to you anyways man but if I may please see the links above, javascript injections are bad in any case `:)`

Comment: @Ahsan.. thanks for reply.. i tried your demo url and implemented it. when i run the program it shows an error message "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Permission denied". Why this error is occuring to me? please help me solve . :)

Comment: Generally, if the parent tries to control an iframe in a different domain you will get this error.

Comment: @AhsanRathod thanks for reply.. i will see to that and send you feedback. i am having another question.. Can we able disable right click over an SWF file when it is loaded via iframe in a asp page.

Comment: @AhsanRathod... That was a good article. thanks for that.. Please give any idea in solving SWF file opened in iframe. Thanks...:)

Comment: Firstly if you think the answer I gave you is acceptable, so mark it as accepted answer. And secondly if you want to disable right click on SWF in an Iframe, So I only say If the SWF file  inside an Iframe is placed on the same domain, then it is possible to disable right click on it.

Comment: See This Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rathoreahsan/gJtkW/2/ My HTML pages is in the same domain, but SWF file is on another domain. Mouse events are working on the blank area inside border. but not working on SWF file.

Comment: @AhsanRathod thanks for the reply. my html page and SWF file is loaded from same domain only.i'm sure about it. then how can i solve that disabling right click issue over SWF file loaded in a iframe. :)

Comment: As I am thinking you want to disable right click because you don't want to show the `flash context menu` to the user, while user click `right button` of the mouse on SWF file.

Comment: @AhsanRathod thanks for reply.You got my point.Any solution for avoiding flash context menu. :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13163/discussion-between-ahsan-rathod-and-neon)

Comment: @AhsanRathod thanks man It worked. If the SWF file is in another domain can i able to control that right click in that SWF file.

Comment: Might be possible with this script.

Comment: @AhsanRathod thanks for reply.. I will try and send you the feedback.

Comment: @AhsanRathod I am having one minor problem in disabling right click in some browsers. In modern browsers like chrome and firefox , they provide an option "Prevent this page from creating additional dialogues". When i checks this option, right click disability is not working. Please give some solution for that situation... Thanks ... :) It is working fine in IE.

Answer (score 2):

Hey: this might help:

[How Enable Right Click in IFRAME with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3597470/how-enable-right-click-in-iframe-with-javascript?rq=1)

or

http://forums.asp.net/p/1818670/5042726.aspx/1?Capture+mouse+right+click+event+inside+a+iframe+using+jquery+

> This is not possible I'm afraid. When you're inside the iframe, you're
>   in a second  tag... Unless you own what's inside the
>   iframe and are able to put your Javascript on the page within then
>   it's impossble. iframes are very limited for many many security
>   reasons.

Please let me know if anyone thinks otherwise, happy to take this post off.

**Although** Try this hack mentioned here: http://www.codingforums.com/archive/index.php/t-8824.html

**or** here http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=371334

cheers,

Comment: I only posted that question in that asp.net forums site. I must need a idea to solve that. Sorry for downvote.

Comment: @Neon ha ha ha ha ha ha :) lol cool so you got the answer right? I will remove my post but lemme know if this is possible, without hack `:)` oh and you down voted because?

Comment: ...Thanks for your reply. i need to solve that issue. if you get any idea in future please reply to this.

Comment: @Neon I have pasted a helpful link above **try using** `context menu` http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=371334 anyhoo not worth a down vote man,

Comment: that tags is not supported in asp.net. can u suggest any other method. Thanks for reply. Is any replacement is there for iframe in asp.net ? :)

Comment: Then you should give him a Demo to explain your point of view.

Comment: @AhsanRathod indeed, I will but if you read again, you do know that its Javascript injection which is not good, making demo will prove the same thing but first point is javascript injection is bad anyways `:)`