# Jquery capture Click on Iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe

So I have an Iframe on my page like

```
<iframe width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" src="http://www.youtube.com/xxxxxx">
```

I was wondering how I could capture the click event on this. The Iframe's do not have an id or class set on them

Comment: Your answer might be here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11223210/capture-mouse-right-click-event-inside-a-iframe-using-jquery

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to capture click event with jQuery for iframe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082623/how-to-capture-click-event-with-jquery-for-iframe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not interact with iframes which are not under the same domain. This is always prevented by the browser's policy.

See [Detect Click into Iframe using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381336/detect-click-into-iframe-using-javascript)

Answer (score 7):

I ran into a situation where I had to track clicks on a social media button pulled in through an iframe. A new window would be opened when the button was clicked. Here was my solution:

```
var iframeClick = function () {
    var isOverIframe = false,
    windowLostBlur = function () {
        if (isOverIframe === true) {
            // DO STUFF
            isOverIframe = false;
        }
    };
    jQuery(window).focus();
    jQuery('#iframe').mouseenter(function(){
        isOverIframe = true;
        console.log(isOverIframe);
    });
    jQuery('#iframe').mouseleave(function(){
        isOverIframe = false;
        console.log(isOverIframe);
    });
    jQuery(window).blur(function () {
        windowLostBlur();
    });
};
iframeClick();
```

Comment: this is the exact scenario i needed help with. your solution is ingenious, thanks!

Comment: Note that this only works on the first click. (Unless mouse leaves and re-enters iframe)