# Triggering click across iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

This is my iframe HTML code :

```
<ul id="titleee" >
<li><a href="http://adskpak.com/?type=2&id=jayvicious">CLick me</a></li>
</ul>
```

This is my main page code :

```
<iframe id="iframe" src="iframe1.php"></iframe>

<script>
$(document).ready( function(){
  $('#iframe').contents().find('#titleee').click();
});
</script>
```

It seems it's not triggering the click event.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery capture Click on Iframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15557155/jquery-capture-click-on-iframe)

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to trigger a click on the anchor tag in the iframe. To do that, you will need to have the trigger code in the iframe document and add a listener for messages from the parent document.

Comment: jQuery won't cause `<a>` to load href anyway when you trigger `click()`

Comment: @macguru2000 , do you have any luck on it?

Comment: You want to make sure that your find() query finds the anchor tag and not the #titleee element.

Comment: What functionality are you looking for? Do you want to click the link? If so, you need to `.find("#titleee a").click()` instead. If you want to trigger a custom click event, the click event has to be bound in the iframe as well. So when you bind your click event, bind it to `$('#iframe').contents()` or with `$('#iframe').contents()` as the context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check the console of your browser for errors:-
You might be getting this error:-

```
SecurityError: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "http://www.goibibo.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
```

This will work if you have both the **parent and the iframe on same domain**. Set **document.domain** of both the page and the iframe to the same value i.e. your domain and then check.

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this should work, although I don't do jQuery anymore, just vanilla Javascript. I'm sure you can figure out how to do it in jQuery.

this is your iframe code:

```
<ul id="titleee" >
<li><a href="http://adskpak.com/?type=2&id=jayvicious">Click me</a></li>
</ul>
<script>
  window.addEventListener("message", function() {
    if (event.origin === 'http://adskpak.com') {
      if (event.data === 'click the link') {
        document.querySelector('#titleee a').click();
      }
    }
  });
</script>
```

now your main page code:

```
<iframe id="iframe" src="iframe1.php"></iframe>
<script>
  var iframeWindow = document.querySelector('#iframe').contentWindow;

  // this needs to happen after the load event,
  // but it is best if it happens on a user's action.
  window.onload = function() {
    iframeWindow.postMessage('click the link', '*');
  }
</script>
```

I've tested this code and it seems to work, although when I did the test I used google.com, which actually alerted me a cross domain error:

```
Load denied by X-Frame-Options: https://www.google.com/ does not permit cross-origin framing.
```

I am not sure if this is relevant for you, as it looks like your doing everything on your own domain, just a heads up.