# How to disable iFrame contextmenu?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to disable iFrame context menu using javascript?

```
<iframe id="frFile"  oncontextmenu="return false"/>
```

but this  is not working

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45156500/6654503

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274338/is-it-possible-to-disable-right-click-on-an-iframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modern browsers don't let you impair usability by blocking context menu's. Its almost not possible to disable context menus insider iframe or for that matter, in almost any part of the page.

Refer to this question for more detailed answer: [Is it possible to disable right click on an iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274338/is-it-possible-to-disable-right-click-on-an-iframe)